# What difference between heave-offering and wave-offering?

Tags: sacrifice

> "'This also is yours, the offering of their gift, even all the wave offerings of the sons of Israel; I have given them to you and to your sons and daughters with you as a perpetual allotment. Everyone of your household who is clean may eat it." Numbers 18:11 NASB, [bolls.life/NASB/4/18/11](https://bolls.life/NASB/4/18/11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to have been a classification of these offerings per [this online article](https://www.biblesprout.com/articles/god/heave-wave-offering/).

> The Heave Offering receives its name from the
>   motion used in its presentation where the priest used an up and down
>   motion–lifting it up to the Lord and receiving it back from Him.
>
> Likewise, the Wave Offering receives its name from
>   the motion used when the priest presented the Wave Offering in a
>   waving type motion. The sacrifice was held in the offerer’s hands,
>   with the priest’s hands underneath the offerer’s, and it was waved
>   forward toward the altar and then backward from the altar–giving it to
>   the Lord and then receiving it back from Him as a gift to the priest.
>
> The right shoulder, better translated right thigh, of the sacrificial
>   animal was a Heave Offering and the breast-piece was a Wave Offering.
>   Both of these pieces were given to the priest to eat, and the rest of
>   the flesh was given to the offerer to eat, sharing it with his family
>   and friends in the presence of the Lord in His sanctuary.
>
> The Heave and Wave Offerings were part of the Peace Offering, which
>   was one of the five Offerings we read about in the book of Leviticus.
>   (The five types of Levitical Offerings were the Burnt Offering, the
>   Meat Offering, the Peace Offering, the Sin Offering, and the Trespass
>   Offering.)
>
> The Peace Offering was the only offering in which
>   the donor received back a portion of the sacrifice to eat himself.
>   Furthermore, it was the only animal sacrifice that did not deal with
>   making atonement for sin. The Meat Offering was the only Offering of
>   the five that did not involve an animal sacrifice–it was a Meal or
>   Cereal Offering instead of an animal sacrifice.